# Launching an application from another using the wrong app.config

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

All our custom applications are currently accessed by staff via a custom Toolbar Menu (not built by myself). This is built using vb and uses the line

```
Process.Start(FileToLaunch, params)
```

The issue I have is I have built an Application that can send push notifications to mobile devices (This is built with `C#, WPF, MVVM, XAML`), and it must use its own app.config for these push Notifications to work. This application works perfectly when running it directly by clicking on its .exe the push notifications are all sent successfully.

On launching it from the `Toolbar Menu Application` via the line of code above, the `Notifications Application` is looking for the config settings in the Toolbar Menu folder instead of the Notifications application.
This is then causing the following error when sending notifications.

> There has been an error, which has been logged.
>
> ***Error Message:*** Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

My colleague says that the only way they have dealt with this in the past is to add all relevant config settings to the `Toolbar Menu Application` app.config.
This does not seem like a good way to work.

If you have any suggestions on how to get the application to launch using the correct config I would be most grateful.

Also please just ask if you need any further information.

Thanks

Comment: If you set working directory on process info then I think that will pick up app.config in there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Andy's suggestion sounds right.  You need to create a `ProcessStartInfo` object and configure that as required, then pass it to `Process.Start` as an argument.

Comment: You cold also consider using shell() in place of process.Start, and that would cause the app to use its own  config. It really depends on how much control the main launcher app needs over the other apps launched.